# CSS grid - Overlapping grid line numbers

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Apologies if this question has already been asked but I haven't been able to find any posts that address this.

My grid has three items: red, green and blue. (**[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmerchant/0sLz5k2t/6/)**)

Red has a row-start property via `grid-area: 6` so it is given priority and placed first. Blue and green are then placed into the grid in their source order. The result looks like this:

[image: ![![enter image description here]

I don't understand this result because it looks as though red has been placed on row 2 despite specifying a row-start of 6 (via `grid-area: 6;`). If you inspect the grid in Firefox devtools, you see that the grid line numbers for rows 2-6 overlap:

[image: ![![enter image description here]

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area), specifying an integer value for grid-area

> contributes the nth grid line to the grid
> item’s placement. If a negative integer is given, it instead counts in
> reverse, starting from the end edge of the explicit grid. If a name is
> given as a , only lines with that name are counted. If
> not enough lines with that name exist, all implicit grid lines are
> assumed to have that name for the purpose of finding this position.

The last sentence doesn't make sense to me - I'm reading it as "since not enough lines with the name '6' exist, all implicit grid lines from 3-6 are assumed to have that name for the purpose of finding this position". Shouldn't the algorithm create rows 3-6 implicitly and then place the red div on row six 6 with whitespace for rows 2-5?

This is the result I was expecting:

[image]

I obtained this by setting `grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 100px);`. (But `grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);` didn't work, not exactly sure why.)

Comment: It's not clear what you were hoping to achieve.  Were you expecting to see "23" on the first line, then some whitespace then "1"?

Comment: Yes, whitespace where rows 2, 3, 4 and 5 should be and then the red div on row 6. Not sure why the post was downvoted.

Comment: I've edited my JSFiddle - the numbers in the divs were just to denote their source order but I can see how they may have confused some people so I've taken them out. The rest of my post is unchanged - my question asks why there is overlap in the grid line numbers (as shown in the blue circle in the second screenshot). Since the red div has property `grid-area: 6;`, shouldn't it be placed on the 6th row with whitespace for rows 2 to 5 since they are empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rows are sizeless, therefore row 6 overlaps rows 2,3,4,5.

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 100px);
}


#red {
  grid-area: 6;
  background-color: red;
}

#green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id='grid'>
  <div id='red'></div>
  <div id='green'></div>
  <div id='blue'></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @M3dython! I can't believe I was so far into the weeds that I missed this. The size of an implicitly-created row track is determined by the size of the items in that track. Since there is no content in rows 2-5, they have a height of 0, hence the "overlap". `grid-auto-rows: 100px;` works too. The documentation excerpt quoted in the OP still doesn't make sense to me though.

Comment: <integer> && <custom-ident>?
Contributes the nth grid line to the grid item’s placement. If a negative integer is given, it instead counts in reverse, starting from the end edge of the explicit grid.
If a name is given as a <custom-ident>, only lines with that name are counted. If not enough lines with that name exist, all implicit grid lines are assumed to have that name for the purpose of finding this position.
Maybe it's because you are naming the row with an integer, not a string. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row-start)